# Parse text from webpage in Java (not html)

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

I am using this code to download a string from a website:

```
static public String getLast() throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    URL url = new URL("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result += str;
    }
    in.close();
    return result;
}
```

When I print the result of this method, this is what I get:

```
{"high": "349.90", "last": "335.23", "timestamp": "1384198415", "bid": "335.00", "volume": "33743.67611671", "low": "300.28", "ask": "335.23"}
```

That's exactly what is shown when you open the URL. This works fine for me, but if there is a more efficient way to do this please let me know.

What I need to extract is 335.23. This number is constantly changing, but the words such as "high", "last", "timestamp", etc always stay the same. I need to extract the 335.23 as a double. Is this possible?

Edit:

**SOLVED**

```
String url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";
    try {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jParser = factory.createParser(new URL(url));
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {

            String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
            if ("last".equals(fieldname)) {
                jParser.nextToken();
                System.out.println(jParser.getText());
                break;
            }

        }
        jParser.close();

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is JSON. Use a good parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). There are also good [Tutorials](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) available.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a json. Use a java JSON Parser and get value for "high" element.
One of the java json parsers is available on (http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String pageName = obj.getString("high");
```

Answer (score 0):

The data String that you have received is known as [**JSON encoding**](http://www.json.org/). `JSON` (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. Use a fine grain [**simple json encoder and decoder**](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to encode and decode data.